# How to transfer an Android application I have developed to another phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment

I have developed my first small Android application using Eclipse and managed to transfer it to my Samsung Galaxy S mobile phone.

My colleague at work has got another Android mobile phone running the same version (Android 2.1).

How can I give him my new application without him needing to install a development environment? Is this possible?

It's an internal program so I don't want to publish it to the Android market (at least, not just yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send him the APK file. He has to enable the setting to install software from unknown sources, but apart from that this should work. :-)

Comment: @mreichelt: what exactly do you mean by 'just send him the APK file' ? Do I copy it over the network to his pc, and he copies it to  ..... a folder on his mobile ?

Comment: Just mail it to him. If he doesn't access his mail directly on his phone, he can also copy it to his phone via USB, install a file explorer like the 'ES File Explorer' and select & install the APK file from his SD card.

Comment: @mreichelt: First of all, thanks for taking the time to respond: but can I ask another question ? We are both on a network, I can put my APK file on a shared network folder. He can attach his phone using USB so he can copy the APK file over to his phone. Can he just do that ? And if yes: how can he select this APK file on his phone ? If not, do you need some sort of install process ... maybe basic questions, but I need to find some easy way to copy the programs I write to another mobile phone - preferable over the internal network.

Comment: As I said: Let him install the ES File Explorer (or any other) and he can navigate to his SD card and install the APK file. Or even better: ES File Explorer can directly access network shares, so if your computer and his phone are in the same network this even gets simpler.

Comment: @mreichelt: Thx, the email methode worked. So I marked the answer ... But just for the record, is it absolutetly necessary to use and install a file manager to install other applications ? Is it not possible somehow to just copy the APK file using USB to a folder on the device and then install it from there ?

Comment: Well, you don't need to have a *file manager* on the device - but you somehow have to tell Android where the APK is which it should install. This can be an app on the device (and most file managers do this pretty well), or you run this command by using 'adb shell'. But for this of course the SDK is needed, so using an app on the device is the more convenient way.

Comment: An alternative to installing the SDK is to install the sideload wonder machine on a windows pc.  (This was created for those with ATT phones which are blocked from installing apk's from a file manager on the phone, but it's not limited to ATT phones)